# Calendar View for Jenkins jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is there a plugin to jenkins(hudson) that can visually show all jobs and there runs in future as well as in the past.

ex: if Job A is scheduled to run once every day at 8 AM. The plugin should show the previous run of the job as well as scheduled runs in the future.

I searched in [Jenkins Plugins Link](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins) and found [Google Calendar](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Google+Calendar+Plugin) but there are two things different about this plugin

1. It is linked to job status hence I am presuming it will only show previous runs
2. It needs an online calendar account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you would have to write such a plugin.

Answer (score 2):

"Next executions" plugin helpful a bit:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Next+Executions

Answer (score 2):

The plug-in [calendar-view](https://plugins.jenkins.io/calendar-view/) is doing what you are looking for.

Features as of version Version: 0.3.1:

#### Features

- Provides a month, week and day view of past and future builds
- Indicates status of past builds by color
- Displays when future scheduled builds will happen
- Shows estimated duration of future scheduled builds
- Configurable date and time settings